# Extract nested fields in Visual Studio Web load test

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, testing, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-test-runner

Here is an html code I would like to test load and extract data from

```
<body>
    <h1>Hello StackOverflow</h1>

    <input type="hidden" name="Secret" value="66"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="Field[66].value" value="333" />
</body>
```

I need the `333` value. To do that, I need to extract the value `66` from `Secret`, and then use this value to deduce the name of the field (here `Field[66].value`).
How can I do that?

I've tried to use two `Extract Attribute Value` extraction rules, but because there are on the same response, the first value is not yet in the context.

Comment: Why the downvote? It may be useful to explain why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to create a `Custom Extraction Rule` as explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms243179.aspx) and to use a regex to parse twice the html body

Extract Method:

```
public override void Extract(object sender, ExtractionEventArgs e)
{
    var val1 = GetInputValueByName(e.Response.BodyString, "Secret");
    var val2 = GetInputValueByName(e.Response.BodyString, $"Field[{val1}].value");

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(val2 ))
    {
        e.Success = true;
        e.WebTest.Context.Add(this.ContextParameterName, val2);
    }
    else
    {
        // If the extraction fails, set the error text that the user sees
        e.Success = false;
        e.Message = String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "Not Found: {0}", Name);
    }

}


private string GetInputValueByName(string html, string name)
{
    Match match = Regex.Match(html, "<input[^>]*name=\"" + Regex.Escape(name) + "\"[^>]*value=\"([^\"]*)\"");
    if (match.Success)
    {
        return match.Groups[1].Value;
    }
    return string.Empty;
}
```